# Pydantic: Make a model fail with ValidationError before field_validators run

Tags: python, pydantic

here is a basic Pydantic model:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator

class FooModel(BaseModel):
    x: int
    y: str

    @field_validator("y")
    @classmethod
    def y_validator(cls, value, values):
        print("Validator depends on x in values:", {values.data["x"]})
        return value
```

The problem with this is that if invalid input is supplied, e.g. `FooModel(x="bar", y="2")`, then the model fails with a `KeyError` from the `field_validator`, not as soon as possible with the `ValidationError` on the value passed for `x`.

How can I make the model instantiation raise a `ValidationError` asap when the type cast fails?

Edit:

One solution could be to use try/except in the validator and pass on any Exception:

```
@field_validator("y")
@classmethod
def y_validator(cls, value, values):
    try:
        print("Validator depends on x in values:", {values.data["x"]})
    except Exception:
        pass

    return value
```

This basically passes the ball to the Pydantic validation mechanism; however I would generally consider `pass` in an `except` block a code smell. Maybe in this case this is justifiable. Opinions?